# Does a group act on the closure of its orbits?

Tags: group-actions, topological-groups, algebraic-groups

Consider a topological group action of a group $G$ on a topological space $X$. Let $O=G.x$ be the orbit of $x\in X$. Under which condition do we get that
$$G.\overline{O}\subset\overline{O}?$$

This is apparently true if $G$ is a linear algebraic group and $X$ a $G$-variety, but I can't see why!

Comment: First of all in the context of algebraic groups and varieties, one considers algebraic actions, not just continuous, and the topology on $G\times X$ is not the product topology. So you can't view it as a particular case, it's just a distinct setting. In the topological setting, the inclusion you're writing is true, it is a consequence of continuity. Hint: consider $\{x\in X:\forall g\in G,gx\in\bar{O}\}$.

Comment: Thank you! I see it. Do you think that if I change the framework with: "Consider a group acting homeomorphically on a topological space...", this would allow me to see both topological groups and algebraic groups as particular cases?

Comment: Yes it seems to work.